# Decide the most favorable candidate

Tags: game-theory, voting-theory, social-choice-theory

Consider an election voting process where people need to elect a representative among n number of candidates.

Is there an approach to determine the most favorable option? Voting just a single person may not be favorable because even if the winner secures say 25% of the total votes, he still maybe actually rejected by 75% of the people.

Comment: This is not a logic problem. Try to be accurate with your tags.

Comment: Could you define "most favorable" mathematically?

Answer (score 4):

Instant-runoff voting (aka [the alternate vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant-runoff_voting)) as opposed to [first past the post voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-past-the-post_voting) (i.e. your method, aka FPTP) fixes this problem. Unfortunately, the USA isn't going to adopt this method any time soon.

You might also be interested in this [list of voting methods and the voting criteria they fulfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instant_runoff_voting_to_other_voting_systems#Voting_system_criteria). Neither the alternate vote nor FPTP voting [produce a Condorcet winner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_criterion), and if you're interested in that, you might want to look into [the Kemeny-Young method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kemeny%E2%80%93Young_method).

Answer (score 1):

If you define "fairness" in a fairly sensible way you get the famous result https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrows_impossibility_theorem